# Task saved as Bug in TFS

Tags: tfs

While working on TFS 2012, I accidentally saved a TASK as a BUG.

Is there any way to work around this?
Can I change the task to bug in any way possible ?

Comment: http://juristr.com/blog/2009/08/howto-changing-tfs-workitem-type-from/

Comment: Welcome to SO :) This is a good question, but something that was this easy to google won't often get a lot of attention.  Also, adding as much context as possible can help.  In this case your "task" tag was inappropriate because it referred to a different concept.  Normally a little more context about the versions you're using will get you better results

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change a type of a workitem. The workaround is to create a copy of the Task workitem as a Bug workitem and change the status of task workitem to closed.